# Angular formArray with multi input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have `FormArray` which gets array of inputs like this:

```
[
  0 "one"
  1 "two"
  2 "three"
]
```

What I want to do is to have my data like this

```
[
  0 [choice: "one", choice_seq_no: "1", is_correct: "0"]
  1 [choice: "two", choice_seq_no: "2", is_correct: "1"]
  2 [choice: "three", choice_seq_no: "3", is_correct: "0"]
]
```

therefore each row has 3 values.

#### Code

`HTML`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let att of skills.controls; let idx = index">
    <ion-label color="primary">{{att.label}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
    
    // currently is equal to `choice` (there is no input for `choice_seq_no` and `is_correct`)
    <ion-input type="text" [formControl]="skills.controls[idx]"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-button type="button" expand="full" type="button" color="light" (click)="Add()">Add More</ion-button>
```

`Component`

```
skills = new FormArray([]);

Add(){
    this.skills.push(new FormControl(''));
}
```

**any idea?**

## Update

I have managed to get array of inputs in my formArray but there are minor issues still need to be solved.

#### Current code

`HTML`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let att of skills.controls; let idx = index">
    <ion-label color="primary">{{idx+1}}</ion-label>

    <ng-container [formGroup]="att">
        <ion-label position="floating">Sequence No.</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="choice_seq_no"></ion-input>
        <ion-label position="floating">Choice</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="choice"></ion-input>
        <ion-label position="floating">Is Correct?</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox formControlName="is_correct"></ion-checkbox>
    </ng-container>
</ion-item>
<ion-button type="button" expand="full" type="button" color="light" (click)="Add()">Add More</ion-button>
```

`Component`

```
Add(){
    const group = new FormGroup({
      choice_seq_no: new FormControl(''),
      choice: new FormControl(''),
      is_correct: new FormControl('')
    });

    this.skills.push(group);
}
```

**Issues**

[image: two]

1. when input is selected all inputs will be select at once and to
   moving into another input must use "tab" key which is not possible
   when using mobile devices

Comment: Instead of pushing a `FormControl`, you should push a `FormGroup` instead.

Comment: @emmbee ok and what about my html? should I add anything there?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not by my computer so it's hard for me to write code now... Just loop over them and use each value as you'd use a regular formgroup

Comment: as emmbee said, formgroup with 3 separate formControls, one for each value that you account for. You may have to do some funky stuff with declaring the name of the formgroup, which for a formArray is the index (it's weird I know), but I've done it and it definitely can be done, best of luck!